# Improvisation Technique and Theory Over Modal Sus or slash chords

Tags: theory, jazz, improvisation, fusion

i would like to understand how to improvise over a Modal Sus chord progression.

As an example you can look at the video down here at 3"00. There Begins a Improvisation by a Keyboarder and later a guitarist over a chord change with Sus or slash chords.

I think the Progression is Gmaj/A , Ebmaj/F , Cmaj/D , Cmaj/D
What would be the right way of thinking about this Progression?
What scales or Arpeggios should be used for Improvisation?

Comment: This was put on hold because it is basically asking "What do they do in this video?", and that kind of analysis of a particular song is considered too specific. If you rephrase it to be more about the general concept you are looking for, and take you-tube out of the title, rather than "How does this guy play this progression," I'd vote to reopen. I think you are trying to get at a general concept, but you are also asking about what and how it is done here. It's a mixed message.

Comment: Change the title and use Lukather's song as an example. I hope this gets reopened because content-wise it's probably one of the more interesting questions here. By the way, the first chord is Gmaj7/A, listen to the bass, it's definitely an A.

Comment: In the progression you mentioned, there are no sus chords

Comment: @Shevliaskovic: There are. C/D is just another way of writing a D9sus4 chord.

Answer (score 1):

When improvising over a progression like this, you need to change scales when the chords change. Since all chords are of the same type, you can use the same scale (with a different root, obviously) over each chord. The appropriate chord scale is mixolydian, but especially in Lukather's solo I can also hear dorian over the first chord Gmaj7/A.

Pentatonic scales sound especially good over such a progression. You could try E minor pentatonic over G/A, G minor pentatonic over Eb/F, and A minor pentatonic over C/D. So, just as an idea, you could play a melody in E minor pentatonic, shift it up by a minor third (G min. pent.), then shift it up another whole tone to A minor pentatonic. This will get you safely over the progression. Minor 7 Arpeggios will also work well. E.g., try Bm7 over G/A, Cm7 over Eb/F, and Am7 (or Em7) over C/D.

You see there are many possibilities that you can play around with. Note that the same type of chord is used in the progression of Herbie Hancock's tune *Maiden Voyage*. Also listen to the solos on that song and learn from them. I've written a [blog post](http://www.mathiaslang.com/2013/01/improvising-over-static-sus4-chords.html) about improvising over suspended chords, using Maiden Voyage as an example. Also check out Toto's version of it called *Butterfly* with Steve Lukather's solo on it.